# Move magento module from navigation menu to a tab in the admin configuration

Tags: magento, magento-backend

I have a widget grid type module, which i want to move into magento system config.

I have added the following into my system.xml:

```
<config>
    <sections>
        <customesetup>
            <groups>
                <serialnumbervalidator>
                    <label>Serial Numbers</label>
                    <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                    <expanded>1</expanded>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <frontend_class>complex</frontend_class>
                    <frontend_model>mymodule/adminhtml_serial</frontend_model>

                </serialnumbervalidator>
            </groups>
        </customesetup>
    </sections>
</config>
```

but apparently it shows nothing. as the Block extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container .

If anyone can point me where to look for my answer this would be great (Did searches and did not find anything useful).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify your config.xml, to show this up in System Configuration section.

```
    <adminhtml>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <system>
                            <children>
                                <config>
                                    <children>
                                        <YOUR_MODULE translate="title">
                                            <title><![CDATA[MY TITLE]]></title>
                                            <sort_order>2100</sort_order>
                                        </YOUR_MODULE>
                                    </children>
                                </config>
                            </children>
                        </system>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
[...]
</adminhtml>
```

And in your system.xml :

```
    <config>
        <tabs>
            <YOUR_MODULE_tab translate="label" module="YOUR_MODULE">
                <label>YOUR_MODULE</label>
                <sort_order>150</sort_order>
                <class>container_admin_img</class> /*optionnal*/
            </YOUR_MODULE_tab>
        </tabs>
        <sections>
            <customesetup>
                <groups>
                    <serialnumbervalidator>
                        <label>Serial Numbers</label>
                        <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                        <expanded>1</expanded>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <frontend_class>complex</frontend_class>
                        <frontend_model>mymodule/adminhtml_serial</frontend_model>

                    </serialnumbervalidator>
                </groups>
            </customesetup>
        </sections>
   </config>
```

Hope this helps.

Take a look at Alan Storm's No Frills Magento Layout book, or on his website : http://alanstorm.com/category/magento

Comment: Thanks that worked, though had to change more things, will add them on request :)